# App memory limit for UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

For Windows Phone 8.x, I used `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit")` to get the max app memory limit. UWP's API `Windows.System.MemoryManager` doesn't have a property or method to provide such information.

Is it possible to know the max memory limit for a UWP app and if so how?

Comment: What about `MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit`? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit.aspx)

Comment: @croxy That didn't make sense to me -- it just shows the device installed memory. If so, it tells me that there is no app memory limit, hence my question if there is a limit.

Comment: See this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Memorylimitbyapptype

Comment: My question is for UWP app, not for Windows Phone 8. Thanks anyway.